# How can be open track changes after acceptance the changes

Tags: windows, windows-10, microsoft-word

I I have amended the word file through track change, after that accepted and saved, how I can see the track changes again

Comment: Short answer: You can't. Once they are accepted they are no longer available to see.

Answer (score 0):

You can restore a previous version of your document. Right click on the file, select either restore previous versions, or document properties. Then select the previous version tab. You can then open the version you want, and do a save as to keep it.